# Search string in user entered data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this type of data in ckeditor

```
<p>test 1</p>

<p>test 2</p>

<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wAARCASwB4ADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHAABAQEAAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcI...k=" /></p>

<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIy7nKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj/2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj/wAARCASwB4ADASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHAABAQEAAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAECA....." /></p>
```

it can be multiple lines or single line of data

```
 <ckeditor formControlName="content" ....>
```

now when user submit the form i want to get base64 string if present.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a base64 string in HTML by looking for an attribute that has a value starting with "data:image/". Here's an example of what a base64 string might look like in an img tag:

```
const html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
const regex = /data:image\/.*;base64,/g;
const matches = html.match(regex);
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: Thanks i tried but is is not storing full string, output is like this `[
    "data:image/jpeg;base64,"
]`

Comment: const html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
const base64Regex = /data:image\/\w+;base64,([\s\S]+)/;
const base64Match = html.match(base64Regex);
if (base64Match) {
  const base64String = base64Match[1];
  console.log(base64String);
}

Comment: function extractBase64String() {
  const html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
  const base64Regex = /data:image\/\w+;base64,([\s\S]+)/;
  const base64Match = html.match(base64Regex);
  if (base64Match) {
    const base64String = base64Match[1];
    console.log(base64String);
  }
}

// Call the extractBase64String() function after the JavaScript code has run.
window.addEventListener('load', extractBase64String);

Comment: try with both code, anyone can work and once get expected result then accept the answer